# Dynamically define an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to dynamically define a directive after page load.

For example running this at some point any page load should output 'in a link' for every `<a>` element:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('a', function() {
    console.log('defining the directive');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function() {
            console.log('in a link');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You want to do something after page load ?

Comment: Yes. [padding for character limit]

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but a directive gets called while rendering html. what is your plan with 'after page load'? i don't get it ...

Comment: For the sample code I gave, `<a>` elements are already in the page HTML. I want to dynamically define a directive ('a') say 5 minutes after page load and have it apply to the existing `<a>` elements and any new ones.

Comment: couldn't you simple add the directive at page-load, and have it react to some injected (service) *on-switch*?

Comment: @Yoshi - Could but don't want to for performance reasons. This is on a very big app with big files.

Comment: there are 2 different problems in your question. 1.lazy-loading the directive after the app is bootstrapped (for this, check https://github.com/doodeec/ng-1.x-async-hack) and 2.forcing existing directives to recompile after the new definition is loaded (I assume you want to do it without page reloading) and this one looks like a bigger problem to me